# Marginal distribution of $P$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Joint distribution of $P$ & $Q$ is

$$f_{P,Q}(p,q)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(2\pi)}\sigma}\exp[-\frac{1}{2}{(\frac{\frac{p+q}{2}-\mu}{\sigma})^2}] \times\theta\exp[-\theta(\frac{p-q}{2})],\quad -\infty<p,q<\infty$$

Now i have to find the marginal pdf of  $P$ & $Q$ .

So i simplified $f_{P,Q}(p,q)$

$$f_{P,Q}(p,q)=\frac{\theta}{2\sqrt{(2\pi)}\sigma}\exp[-\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}]\exp[-\frac{p^2}{8\sigma^2}-\frac{p\mu}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{\theta p}{2}]\exp[-\frac{q^2}{8\sigma^2}-\frac{q\mu}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\theta q}{2}]\exp[-\frac{pq}{4\sigma^2}],\quad -\infty<p,q<\infty$$

marginal pdf of  $P$
$$f_{P}(p)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{P,Q}(p,q)dq$$
$$=\frac{\theta}{2\sqrt{(2\pi)}\sigma}\exp[-\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}]\exp[-\frac{p^2}{8\sigma^2}-\frac{p\mu}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{\theta p}{2}]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp[-\frac{q^2}{8\sigma^2}-\frac{q\mu}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\theta q}{2}-\frac{pq}{4\sigma^2}]dq$$

Then i couldn't solve the integration.

Answer (score 1):

A solution approach is to manipualte the integral so that you obtain limits of integration $[0,\infty]$ and then apply a specific formula that I will give in a while.

Denote for compactness the integrand $A(q^2, q)$.
Then 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A(q^2, q)dq = \int_{-\infty}^{0}A(q^2, q)dq+\int_{0}^{\infty}A(q^2, q)dq $$

By standard properties of the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}A(q^2, q)dq =  \int_{\infty}^{0}A((-q)^2, -q)dq = -\int_{0}^{\infty}A(q^2, -q)dq$$

So $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A(q^2, q)dq =\int_{0}^{\infty}A(q^2, q)dq -  \int_{0}^{\infty}A(q^2, -q)dq$$

Now write carefully the two versions of the integrand as a polynomial in $q^2$ and $q$, or $-q$, and then the following holds -from Gradshteyn & Ryzhik (2007) "Table of Integrals, Series and Products (7th ed), p. 336, eq. 3.322(1):

$$\int_0^{\infty} \exp \left \{-\frac{1}{4b}x^2-cx\right \}dx= \sqrt {\pi b}\exp \left \{bc^2\right \}\Big[1-erf(c\sqrt b)\Big] \qquad b>0$$

Match coefficients and proceed. Be careful with the signs. Lots of algebra ahead. At the end, remember the relation of the error function with the standard normal cdf.